# How to find the values of $a$ that make $\det A= 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a & 6 & 7\\
> a &-8 & 9\\
> 3 &-9 & a\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Find the values of $a$ so that $\det A=0$

When I do it I get $a = 5.54$ or $a = -4.25$  but when I substitute those values back to find determinant I don't get $\det A=0$

Comment: Can you show the steps that you took to get the mentioned values of $a$ ? When you calculate the determinant as a function of $a$, you should get a polynomial of degree 2.

Comment: Are you using the exact values of $a$? Your values are correct but maybe something went wrong for you while checking, so please add some context to your post.

Comment: You should show us your resolution.

Comment: The insight by @TobyMak is right. Do you think you should get exactly $0$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Just solve the following equation.
$$a\cdot(-8)\cdot a+3\cdot6\cdot9+7\cdot a\cdot(-9)-3\cdot(-8)\cdot7-a\cdot(-9)\cdot9-a\cdot a\cdot6=0.$$
I got $$7a^2-9a-165=0,$$ which gives $$\left\{\frac{9+\sqrt{4701}}{14},\frac{9-\sqrt{4701}}{14}\right\}.$$
Now, if you'substitute these values, you'll get that the determinat is equal to $0$.

You got that $\det A\neq0$ because you took an approximated values of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the determinant to zero, we seek to solve for $a$ in
\begin{equation*}
\det A = a(-8a+81) - 6(a^2 - 27) + 7(-9a+24) = -14a^2 + 18a + 330 = 0.
\end{equation*}
Use the quadratic formula to find
\begin{equation*}
a = \frac{18 \pm \sqrt{18804}}{28}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: The OP knows that, check his values.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Using your values given with two presumably exact decimals, we can infer

$$5.53<a<5.55,$$

and observe

$$\left.\det(A)\right|_{a=5.53}=-0.7037,\\\left.\det(A)\right|_{a=5.55}=+0.6675.$$

So there is indeed a root in that range.

Answer (score 0):

That's no surprise. If you use an approximate value for the roots, you'll get approximate values for the determinant.

It's not really different from $1.41^2=1.9881$ and $1.4142^2=1.99996164$. Neither is “exactly $2$”.

```
> gp
                            GP/PARI CALCULATOR Version 2.11.3 (released)
                    i386 running darwin (x86-64/GMP-6.2.0 kernel) 64-bit version
               compiled: Mar  4 2020, Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
                                      threading engine: single
                           (readline v8.0 enabled, extended help enabled)

                               Copyright (C) 2000-2018 The PARI Group

PARI/GP is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and comes WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY
WHATSOEVER.

Type ? for help, \q to quit.
Type ?17 for how to get moral (and possibly technical) support.

parisize = 8000000, primelimit = 500000
? A=[a,6,7;a,-8,9;3,-9,a]
%1 =
[a  6 7]

[a -8 9]

[3 -9 a]

? polroots(matdet(A))
%2 = [-4.2545599189776995286102380535693524985 + 0.E-38*I, 5.5402742046919852428959523392836382128 + 0.E-38*I]~
? a=5.54;eval(matdet(A))
%3 = 0.037599999999999999999999999999999999957
? a=5.54027;eval(matdet(A))
%4 = 0.00057657940000000000000000000000000082196
? a=5.54027420469;eval(matdet(A))
%5 = 2.7223174805459999999999999809257144185 E-10
?
```

As you see, if I use more decimal digits for the value of the root, the determinant becomes nearer to $0$.

The approximation is not really good when you use $5.54$.

Answer (score -1):

For a matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}$$ the determinant [is equal to](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-determinant.html) $$a(ei-fh)-b(di-fg)+c(dh-eg)$$

For your example, $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&6&7\\a&-8&9\\3&-9&a\end{pmatrix}$$

We put this into the formula and get

\begin{align}\det A &= a(-8a-(-9\times 9))-6(a\times a-(9\times 3))+7(-9a-(-8\times 3))\\
&=a(-8a+81)-6(a^2-27)+7(-9a+24)\\
&=-8a^2+81a-6a^2+162-63a+168\\
&=-14a^2+18a+330\end{align}

Now we need to solve this for $\det A=0$, so we say \begin{align}-14a^2+18a+330&=0\\
14a^2-18a-330&=0\end{align}

This is a quadratic equation, so we can solve this in the normal way to get \begin{align}a_1&=\frac1{14}(9-\sqrt{4701})\\
a_2&=\frac 1{14}(9+\sqrt{4701})\end{align}

If we round these to 2 decimal places, as you have done, then we get \begin{align}a_1&\approx-4.25\\
a_2&\approx5.54\end{align}

which are the values that you had found.

When checking the answers, you need to use the exact result, i.e. the ones with the square roots in them, otherwise you will encounter rounding errors which is presumably where your confusion is coming from.

Comment: The OP knows that, check his values.

Comment: I've updated to clarify that, I hadn't noticed their answers were rounded versions of the actual answers

Comment: ah yes, i had to use the exact values...thanks alot for the help guys!